# Button not firing inside Accordion Panes inside which is inside Update Panel

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am customizing one website but , while using triggers in update panel the click event is not firing.

SOURCE CODE:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
```

Also see the `Content Template`

```
<ContentTemplate>
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <cc1:accordion id="Accordion1" runat="server" headercssclass="headeraccordian">
    <panes>
              <cc1:accordionpane ID="AccordionPane1" runat="server">
          <header>
               <a href="#">
                 <asp:Label ID="dailyreport" CssClass="lbl" runat="server" Text="Daily Report"></asp:Label></a>
         </header>
       <content>
              <div>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" Width="94px"></asp:TextBox>
                  <asp:Button ID="btnCal" runat="server" Text="Select Date" OnClick="btnCal_Click" />
                 &nbsp;
                  <asp:Button ID="btnDownLoads" runat="server" Text="Download" OnClick="btnDownLoads_Click" />
                <asp:Calendar ID="cal" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="cal_SelectionChanged" BackColor="White"
                     BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="Black"
                     Height="190px" NextPrevFormat="FullMonth" Width="350px">
                     <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#333399" ForeColor="White" />
                     <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                    <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />
                    <NextPrevStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#333333" VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
                    <DayHeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt" />
                    <TitleStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="4px" Font-Bold="True"
                    Font-Size="12pt" ForeColor="#333399" />
               </asp:Calendar>
            </div>
     </content>
            </cc1:accordionpane>
    </panes>
    </cc1:accordion>
                   </td>
                 </tr>
            </table> </ContentTemplate>
```

Also see the triggers

```
<Triggers>
   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnDownLoads" EventName="Click"/>
</Triggers></asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Do let me know why it is not happening

Comment: Trigger will not work with `UpdateMode="Conditional`.

Comment: @صفي: So what should I change ?

Comment: set `UpdateMode="Always"`.

Comment: @صفي:Tried with that also, still not working..! I deleted the button and again created but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Remove triggers. It will start working fine.

Comment: Then use PostBackTrigger instead of Async Trigger

Answer (score 0):

If the button is in the header section you should put:
SuppressHeaderPostbacks="False"

In the AccordionPane.

That worked for me.